# how to use django markdown in my blog

Tags: django

at first I successfully install django markdown

```
 pip install django-markdown
```

than I add django-markdown in my setting.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog',
'django-markdown',
]
```

then, I change my urls.py like as:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from resume import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
     url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog',app_name='blog')),
     url('^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
  ]
```

I also change my admin.py file like as:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','author','publish','status')
    list_filter = ('status','created','publish','author')
    search_fields = ('title','body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ['status','publish']
   # Register your models here.
   admin.site.register(Post,MarkdownModelAdmin, PostAdmin)
```

but, when I start my runserver, django gives me an error like this:

```
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-markdown'
```

how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In installed apps you should add `django_markdown` instead of `django-markdown`

Comment: now through an error like this:    TypeError: register() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Regarding the new error, go look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/) and read about using Django admin site. :)